# How to break the for loop using state

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have code as below. 
I need to break the loop when first match is found.

```
 const [isCodeValid, setIsCodeValid] = useState(false);
      for (let i = 0; i < properyIds.length; i++) {
        if (isCodeValid) {
          break; // this breaks it but had to click twice so state would update
        }
        if (!isCodeValid) {
          firestore().collection(`properties`)
            .doc(`${properyIds[i]}`)
            .collection('companies').get()
            .then(companies => {
              companies.forEach(company => {
                if (_.trim(company.data().registrationCode) === _.trim(registrationCode.toUpperCase())) {
                  console.log("should break here")
                  // updating state like this wont take effect right away
                  // it shows true on second time click. so user need to click twice right now. 
                  setIsCodeValid(true);   
                }
              });
            })
        }
      }
```

state won't update right away so `if (!isCodeValid)` only works on second click.

Once I find match I need to update state or variable so I can break the for loop.

I tried to use a variable but its value also not changing in final if condition, I wonder what is the reason? can anyone please explain ?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function YourComponent({ properyIds }) {
  const [isCodeValid, setIsCodeValid] = useState(false);

  async function handleSignupClick() {
    if (isCodeValid) {
      return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < properyIds.length; i++) {
      const companies = await firestore()
        .collection(`properties`)
        .doc(`${properyIds[i]}`)
        .collection('companies')
        .get();
      for (const company of companies.docs) {
        if (_.trim(company.data().registrationCode) === _.trim(registrationCode.toUpperCase())) {
          setIsCodeValid(true);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return (<button onClick={handleSignupClick}>Sign Up</button>);
}
```

If you await these checks, that will allow you to sequentially loop and break out with a simple `return`, something you can't do inside of a callback. Note that if this is doing database queries, you should probably show waiting feedback while this is taking place so the user knows that clicking did something.

**Update**:

You may want to do all these checks in parallel if feasible so the user doesn't have to wait. Depends on your situation. Here's how you'd do that.

```
async function handleSignupClick() {
  if (isCodeValid) {
    return;
  }

  const allCompanies = await Promise.all(
    properyIds.map(id => firestore()
      .collection(`properties`)
      .doc(`${properyIds[i]}`)
      .collection('companies')
      .get()
    )
  );

  setIsCodeValid(
    allCompanies.some(companiesSnapshot => 
      companiesSnapshot.docs.some(company => 
        _.trim(company.data().registrationCode) === _.trim(registrationCode.toUpperCase())
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: this is on button press function so cant really use useEffect. its on signUp button

Comment: I see. Still, similar code can go in a click handler. Will update.

Comment: I tired both of you solution they didnt work in my case. firebase call need forEach I think. I could not find any documentation though. for (const company of companies) would not work as well

Comment: I see, it's a query snapshot and not an Array, perhaps? https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html

Comment: Updated if that's the case and these are snapshots. Simply add a `.docs` to these to get at the Array so you can use stuff like `.some` and `for..of` loops.

Comment: That is really useful information Jacob. appreciate it. I posted an answer too. I am surprised it worked the simpler way without changing much.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61647796/10516241

Answer (score 2):

You should try and rewrite your code such that you will always call `setIsCodeValid(value)` once. In your case it could be called multiple times and it might not get called at all

```
 const [isCodeValid, setIsCodeValid] = useState(false);

 function checkForValidCode() {
    // map to an array of promises for companies[]
    const companiesPromises = properyIds.map(propertyId => 
          firestore()
            .collection(`properties`)
            .doc(propertyId)
            .collection('companies').get())

    Promise.all(companiesPromises)
        // flatten the 2d array to single array, re-create to JS array because of firestores internal types?
        .then(companiesArray => [...companiesArray].flatMap(v => v)) 
        // go through all companies to find a match
        .then(companies => 
            companies.find(
                company => _.trim(company.data().registrationCode) === _.trim(registrationCode.toUpperCase())
             ))
        .then(foundCompany => {
            // code is valid if we found a matching company
            setIsCodeValue(foundCompany !== undefined)
        })
 }
```

Comment: it says company.data is not a function. I found it only works with forEach.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not break it after `setIsCodeValid(true);`?

Comment: its forEach so i cant use break; to break it. I need to update some variable or state and check at top

Answer (score 0):

Use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
companies.some(company => {
   return _.trim(company.data().registrationCode) === _.trim(registrationCode.toUpperCase());
});
```

If `some` and `forEach` are not available then `companies` is not an array but an array-like object. To iterate through those, we can use `for of` loop:

```
for (const company of companies){
   if (_.trim(company.data().registrationCode) === _.trim(registrationCode.toUpperCase())) {
      // do something
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think firebase response works with only forEach.. it gives me this error. TypeError: companies.some is not a function

Comment: That's weird. As arrays have both `forEach` and `some`.
Anyways, why don't you use simple `for of` loop then?


for (var company of companies) {
    if (condition) break; }

Answer (score 0):

I tired below and it worked for me to break the loop.

I declared and tried to change this variable `let codeValid` and it was just not updating its value when match found. (not sure why)

But all of a sudden I tried and it just works.

I didnt change any actual code except for variable.

```
   let codeValid = false;
      let userInformation = []
      for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        console.log("called")
        const companies = await firestore().collection(`properties`)
          .doc(`${properties[i].id}`)
          .collection('companies').get()
          .then(companies => {
            companies.forEach(company => {
              if (_.trim(company.data().registrationCode) === _.trim(registrationCode.toUpperCase())) {
                //     a += 1;
                codeValid = true;
                userInformation.registrationCode = registrationCode.toUpperCase();
                userInformation.companyName = company.data().companyName;
                userInformation.propertyName = properties[i].propertyName;
              }

            });
          })
        if (codeValid) {
          break;
        }
      }
```